# TinyMCE custom stylesheets for different post types

Tags: functions, tinymce, css, wp-enqueue-style

I use a custom stylesheet for TinyMCE, by placing custom styles in `editor-style.css` in my theme's directory.

I am trying to figure out how to use a different stylesheet depending on what post type we are editing.

One way of getting different styles in TinyMCE is to toggle a class in the TinyMCE iFrame's `<body>` tag. I have seen this in the New York Times' [ICE editor plugin](https://github.com/NYTimes/ice), a javascript version of Microsoft Word's "track changes" functionality that can be used with TinyMCE. That's how it toggles visibility of edits without changing the post's HTML. Here's a self-contained example of this:

```
var toggleBodyClass = function() {

    var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
    var body = ed.getBody()
    var cm = ed.controlManager;

    if(ed.dom.hasClass(body,'code-view')) {
        ed.dom.removeClass(body, 'myCustomClass');
    } else {
        ed.dom.addClass(body, 'myCustomClass');
    }

    ed.execCommand('mceRepaint');
}
```

This doesn't allow me to use a separate stylesheet per se, but I can use `.myCustomClass` to create alternate all the alternate styles I want in `editor-style.css`.

The thing is, I'm not sure how I could set up something like this to be conditional on post type.

Is there something I can add to `functions.php` to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

As of 3.4, some classes have been added to TinyMCE so you can target them, including for custom post types. So, for instance, you will see `post-type-{$slug}` as a class on the body. See [Trac ticket #19437](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19437) for more information.